# mysql order by greater than

Tags: php, mysql, database

How i can select something from database by using greater than?

I using this code but no luck

```
SELECT *FROM X WHERE Y=:5 **ORDER BY (Z > 5) DESC LIMIT 5**
```

Im just trying to take the X where Z is greater than 5 but only 5 of them

Comment: Please post the error message text.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may try this to get your results without limit:

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y = 5 AND Z > 5 ORDER BY Z DESC
```

and if you really need to limit your result:

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y = 5 AND Z > 5 ORDER BY Z DESC LIMIT 5
```

Check this fiddle that I made for you:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56f17/3

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do. This will select the first five tuples from your table `X` where the `Y` field is greater than 5. Additionally, the output will be ordered by the field `Z`.

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y > 5 ORDER BY Z DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

this won't work ... you order by a field and don't put condition in order by. Probably you can try like

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y=5 and Z > 5 ORDER BY Z DESC LIMIT 5
```